# including kinect 2.0 SKD with visual studio 2015, windows 10 and openframeworks

Tags: visual-studio-2015, windows-10, kinect-sdk

I have started to work on an existing project where i need to add kinect features.
The project was developed on visual studio 2015, on a windows 10 machine, and uses openframeworks.

I'm having trouble when following tutorials for including the SDK in the project, because there is always a point where what i have differs from what the tutorial expects (i'm also not used to visual studio, or windows, so maybe i just need a better tutorial).

On the Kinect SDK [website](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=44561), it says the sdk requires Embedded 8 Standard, Windows 8 or Windows 8.1, and Visual Studio 2012 or Visual Studio 2013 (system requirements).
I thought this meant "at least windows 8.1", but i'm starting to think i should downgrade to windows 8.1 .

What do you think?

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

I'm also going to start a project using Kinect sensor. So I have also reading about Kinect for Windows SDK compatibility for Windows 10 and with VS 2015.

I think if Windows 10 can detect the Kinect device and all of its components like camera, audio array, etc. you can develop using the Kinect on Windows 10. 
I don't think VS 2015 can cause a problem since it is just adding an library (Microsoft.Kinect.dll) and use with the code.

Hope this post helps you: [Running Kinect for Windows applications on Windows 10 – Things you should verify](http://dailydotnettips.com/2015/08/01/running-kinect-for-windows-applications-on-windows-10-things-you-should-verify/)

I'm going to try installing Kinect for Windows SDK on Windows 10 and use it with VS 2015. I'll update you with the results soon.

Comment: oops, i didnt see your answer... I managed to get the colorSource and depht source in my app, but now i'm trying to track the user's head and the 'CreateFaceFrameSource' function is not working. Should i post a new question for this?